# AHK, holding button

Tags: autohotkey, gaming

I hope this is the right place to ask. I want the LButton to be executed normally if tapped but want RButton to be pressed when held down. Example: I spam LButton and do a light attack but holding LBUtton down for 1 second will Execute RBUtton (Heavy attack). I searched the forums but most requests concerning holding down dont fit my intent.

Thank you!! (Sorry but couldn't be bothered to search all 168 pages for a fitting tag)

Comment: you don't have to look at all tags in the list. Type some characters and it'll be suggested

Comment: Not the question but not allowed to make a user tag since im not signed in

Comment: why do you need to create a tag? even normal users don't have that permission. and there's already [tag:autohotkey] tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you're after, what about something like this?...

```
#SingleInstance, Force
#NoEnv
#NoTrayIcon
#Persistent 

; tilde allows LButton to click as normal vs. this routine capturing the click
; i.e., LButton will always click once prior to RButton click getting sent 1 sec later
~LButton::      
    StartTick:=A_TickCount
    While GetKeyState("LButton", "P") && ((A_TickCount-StartTick)<1000)      ; 1000ms hold-down requirement
        Sleep 10

    If GetKeyState("LButton", "P")  ; If LButton is still down after loop exits, send RButton
        SendInput, {RButton}
Return
```